# D3 Drag an arc's endAngle around a circle (creating a range slider)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, automatic-ref-counting, rangeslider

I am trying to create a dial that allows me to drag the end angle of an arc around a circle to create a range slider.

I have implemented an arc with a start point which denotes the start of the range. I am able to drag the arc to a certain point around the circle with the handle (the black dot), but as you can see in the fiddle, it starts to behave weirdly once going below 0 degrees or above 180 degrees.

I am pretty sure there is a simple check to update `_atanXY` that possibly needs to go in before I call the transition:

```
        _this.valueArc.transition()
        .duration(0)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(-_atanXY));
```

Any help much appreciated. A big bonus would be to have the handle initialise at the end of the orange arc when initialising.

I have created a JS Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/daveashman/fykwmf3e/ with the code below:

```
var dataSet = [];

// var startAngle = -130;
// var endAngle = startAngle + 260; 

var DIAL = function(options) {

var _this = this,
    valueArc;

var defaults = {
    type: 'single-select', // single-select, range-select, drag-range
    width: 395,
    height: 395,
    donutWidth: 25,
    range: 25,
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360,
    selector: '#dial',
    numDegrees: 360,
    piePadding: 0.01
};

this.options = _.extend({}, defaults, options);

this.options.endAngle = this.options.startAngle + this.options.numDegrees;

var radius = Math.min(this.options.width, this.options.height) / 2;

this.initDial = function() {

    var svg = d3.select(this.options.selector)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', this.options.width)
        .attr('height', this.options.height)
        .attr('class', 'circle-segments')
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (this.options.width / 2) + ',' + (this.options.height / 2) + ')');

    var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - this.options.donutWidth)
        .outerRadius(radius)

    var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on('end', dragended)

    function dragstarted(d) {
        d3.select(this).raise().classed('dragging', true);
    }
    var position = [0, 0];
    var d;

    function dragged(d) {

        var halfDW = _this.options.donutWidth;
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        d_from_origin = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(d3.event.y, 2));
        alpha = Math.acos(d3.event.x / d_from_origin);

        var _atanXY = Math.atan(d3.event.x / d3.event.y)

        _this.valueArc.transition()
            .duration(0)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween(-_atanXY));

        d3.select(this)
            .attr("cx", d.x = (radius - (halfDW / 2)) * Math.cos(alpha))
            .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y < 0 ? -(radius - (halfDW / 2)) * Math.sin(alpha) : (radius - (halfDW / 2)) * Math.sin(alpha));

    }

    function dragended(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).classed('dragging', false);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ARC START
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    this.arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - this.options.donutWidth + 2)
        .outerRadius(radius - 2)

    this.valueArc = svg.append('path').datum({
            startAngle: _this.options.startAngle * (Math.PI / 180),
            endAngle: _this.options.startAngle * (Math.PI / 180)
        })
        .style("fill", "orange")
        .attr('id', 'value-arc')
        .attr('stroke', 'orange')
        .attr('stroke-width', 4 - this.options.piePadding)
        .attr("d", this.arc)
        .each(function(d) { this._current = d; });

    _this.setArcEndAngle(this.valueArc, _this.options.endAngle - 100, _this.options.startAngle);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ARC END
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // HANDLE START
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    this.handleArc = svg.append('circle')
        .attr('r', radius - this.options.donutWidth)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('strokeWidth', 20)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('class', 'circumference');

    this.handleData = [{
        x: 0,
        y: -radius + (_this.options.donutWidth / 2)
    }];

    this.handle = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "dot")
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(this.handleData)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", this.options.donutWidth / 2)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(drag);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // HANDLE END
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

}

function arcTween(newAngle) {

    return function(d) {
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
        return function(t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            return _this.arc(d);
        };
    };
}
this.setArcEndAngle = function(arc, endAngle) {
    endAngle = endAngle * (Math.PI / 180);
    arc.transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(endAngle));
}


this.initDial();

return this;

 }

$(document).ready(function() {
var dial = new DIAL({
    type: 'drag-range',
    startAngle: -130,
    numDegrees: 260,
    range: 52,
    selector: '#dial1',
    height: 400,
    width: 400
});


})
```

Thanks.

Dave